# When I append a new row with dynamic inputs to shiny datatable the previous row checkbox input loses reactivity in R

Tags: r, datatables, shiny, reactive

check for a reactivevalues element when appended to contain a checkbox input then how to reflect the current value of a checkbox rather than the first ever default selected

```
shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(dataTableOutput('foo'), actionButton("save_changes","add")),
    #server side computing server = function(input, output) {
        # Collection configuration table
        # create a character vector of shinyinputs
        shinyInputadd = function(FUN, len, id, labl ,...) {
            iter = character(len) inputs = as.character(FUN(paste0(id, len), label = labl, ...)) inputs
        }
        rowcount <- reactiveValues(cnt = 0) 
        output$foo <- DT::renderDataTable({
            DT=bvals$data DT$ID <- NULL datatable(
                DT,
                escape=F,
                selection = 'none',
                rownames = FALSE,
                options = list(
                    pageLength = 20,
                    autoWidth = FALSE,
                    scrollX = FALSE,
                    scrollY = '500px',
                    dom = 't',
                    ordering = FALSE,
                    preDrawCallback = JS('function() {
                        Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node());
                    }'),
                    drawCallback = JS('function() {
                        Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node());
                    }')
                )
            )
        })
        bvals <- reactiveValues(
            data = data.frame(
                "ID" = "None",
                "SELECT" = "None",
                "SEGMENT" = "None",
                "SCENARIO" = "None",
                "REMOVE" = "None"
            )[0,]
        )
        #when user clicks 'Add '
        observeEvent(
            input$save_changes,
            {
                rowcount$cnt <- rowcount$cnt + 1 n <- rowcount$cnt
                #remove rows with value None
                batchdt = bvals$data dt_sel_id <- data.frame(
                    "SELECT" = shinyInputadd(
                        checkboxInput,
                        n,
                        "bcheckb_",
                        "",
                        value = TRUE
                    ),
                    "ID" = n
                )
                #Create a dataframe with one row having Delete button
                dt_rem_button <- data.frame(
                    "REMOVE" = shinyInputadd(
                        actionButton,
                        n,
                        "bdelete_",
                        "",
                        align = "right",
                        class ="needed",
                        icon("minus-circle"),
                        style="color: #b22222; background-color: #fff ;height = 70px ;width = 70px"
                    )
                )
                dt_bind <- cbind(
                    dt_sel_id,
                    data.frame(
                        "SEGMENT" = 1,
                        "SCENARIO" = 1
                    ),
                    dt_rem_button
                )
                #Append new row with new seqUence and the above buttons to the existing values in the collection table
                bvals$data <- rbind(
                    bvals$data,
                    dt_bind
                )
            }
        )
    }
)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thank's for your contribution! Please try to edit your question to include the essential parts of the code. Here you can read about general guidelines for good questions: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for posting the code, but I'm still having trouble understanding your problem. What is it doing now? Can you restate what you want it to do?

Comment: I am trying to add a dynamic row which then can be modified for its value but every time I do that it retains the first ever value set for the current created input element. Currently what it does is retain the value of the input element when it first creates a row